# What are these two questions asking about? 云南石林的风景怎么样？ and 小李为什么想再去云南？

Tags: meaning

> 小王：
>
> 你好！
>
> 最近我在云南的大森林里工作了五个月，今天才回信，请原谅。、
>
> 云南省非常好玩儿！云南菜也很好吃，“过桥面”是我最喜欢的。我最喜欢昆明市，因为那儿的气候很好，四季如春。
>
> 在云南人们用大象搬远树木，很有趣！森林里有很多动物：小熊猫、黑熊等等。
>
> 云南还有世界闻名的石林。那儿的风景很美，有山有水，像中国的山水画儿一样。我很想再去云南画那里的风景。
>
> 请尽快回信！
>
> 你的朋友
>
> 小李
> <sub>(transcribed from [original photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXP6s.jpg))</sub>

- 云南石林的风景怎么样？
- 小李为什么想再去云南？

I know the meaning of every word in these two questions, but struggle to understand them as a whole.

**Question**: What are these two questions asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
云南石林的风景怎么样？
```

How is the scenery in [Shilin, Yunnan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Forest/)?

```
小李为什么想再去云南？
```

Why does Xiao Li want to go to Yunnan again?

Is this what you are asking?